# Typescript Union types with multiple discriminating keys

Tags: typescript

**Problem Statement:**

When creating a union type that consists of objects with various fields where some types contain multiple discriminating keys, typescript is not able to ascertain which type is the correct one for error messages.

I am sure I'm doing something wrong, but I am trying to get to a place where the error messages are intuitive for this function call.

**Code:**

```
interface A1 {
  name: "A";
  type: 1;
  location: "some" | "string" | "literal" | "types";
  subType: "more" | "string" | "literal" | "types";
}

interface A2 {
  name: "A";
  type: 2;
  location: "some" | "string" | "literal" | "types" | "can" | "be" | "shared";
  subType: "not" | "shared";
}

interface B {
  name: "B";
  type: 1;
  location: "could" | "still" | "be" | "shared";
  subType: "probably" | "not";
}

interface C {
  name: "C";
  notype: "field" | "test";
}

type Events = A1 | A2 | B | C;

async function trackIt({ name, ...payload }: Events): Promise<boolean> {
  // do somethng cool.
  return true;
}

trackIt({
  name: "A",
  type: 2,
  location: "some",
  subType: "not a correct literal"
});
```

**Sandbox:**

https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-pond-918m1?fontsize=14

**Desired Error Message for the incorrect 'trackIt' call:**

"'not a correct literal' cannot be applied to 'not' | 'shared'" (correctly identifying that we are dealing with an A2 type but that the subType is incorrect.)

**Actual Error Message:**

"Argument of type '{ name: "A"; type: 2; location: "some"; subType: "not a correct literal"; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Events'.
  Type '{ name: "A"; type: 2; location: "some"; subType: "not a correct literal"; }' is not assignable to type 'B'.
    Types of property 'name' are incompatible.
      Type '"A"' is not assignable to type '"B"'."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't really let you customize errors.  There is an [open suggestion](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23689) to allow something like `Invalid<T>` where a compiler error is generated whenever some type gets evaluated to it, and it outputs the type `T` as the message.  Unfortunately this hasn't been implemented yet, and the available workarounds are fairly ugly.

The general problem you're facing here seems to the compiler's inability to figure out the most relevant reason (from the developer's point of view) for something to fail to type check.  If you've got a value that's supposed to be, but isn't, assignable to a union type like `X | Y | Z`, the compiler has to decide which one of those members to complain about.  It uses some sort of heuristic, but there are always edge cases.  I see another [open suggestion](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18403) to somehow improve this by picking "the closest" member, but it doesn't detail exactly what "closest" means (so the issue needs a proposal), and in any case it's not part of the language yet.

So, what can we do?  If you don't mind making some complicated types based on generics and conditional types, you could kind of lead the compiler down the path of narrowing the union on each property in turn.  My intuition is something like: have a union `U`... and initialize it as `Events`.  Then look at the candidate value passed into `trackIt()`.  First examine the `name` property.  If any of the members of `U` match, narrow `U` to just those values.  Otherwise, leave `U` alone.  Then do the same, for the `type`, `location`, and `subType` properties, in turn.  At the end, `U` will be, in some sense, the "closest" to the candidate value's type.  Then you want to make the compiler compare the candidate value to `U`, and hopefully the errors will be more targeted.

Here's my implementation of that:

```
// Idx<T, K> looks up the K property of T, or returns never 
type Idx<T, K extends keyof any> = K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never;

// IfNever<T, V> evaluates to T unless T is never, in which case it is V
type IfNever<T, V> = [T] extends [never] ? V : T

// DiscriminateBy<U, K, T> takes a union type U, a key type K, and a candidate
// type T, and narrows U to all those whose values at the K property match that
// of T.  This might end up returning never, if there is no match.
type DiscriminateBy<U, K extends keyof any, T> =
    U extends any ? Idx<T, K> extends Idx<U, K> ? U : never : never

// Zoom<U, K, T> is similar to DisciminateBy<U, K, T>, but if there is no
// match it returns the full union U.
type Zoom<U, K extends keyof any, T>
    = IfNever<DiscriminateBy<U, K, T>, U>;

// Given E, EventsWithBetterErrors<E> uses Zoom to focus in on
// the Events union by comparing name, type, location, and subType properties,
// in that order.  
type EventsWithBettorErrors<E> =
    E extends Events ? E :
    Zoom<Zoom<Zoom<Zoom<Events, "name", E>, "type", E>,
        "location", E>, "subType", E>

// the call signature of trackIt is generic, where the e parameter will
// be inferred as having type E, and it is then compared to EventsWithBetterErrors<E>
async function trackIt<E>(e: EventsWithBettorErrors<E>): Promise<boolean>;
// keep the simpler implementation signature
async function trackIt({ name, ...payload }: Events) {
    return true;
}
```

Inline comments sort of explain it, I hope.

Now let's see how it works:

```
trackIt({
    name: "A",
    type: 1,
    location: "types",
    subType: "literal"
}) // okay
```

So a valid call still compiles.  Let's try your example:

```
trackIt({
    name: "A",
    type: 2,
    location: "some",
    subType: "oops" // error!
    // Type '"oops"' is not assignable to type '"shared" | "not"'.
});
/* function trackIt<{
    name: "A";
    type: 2;
    location: "some";
    subType: "oops";
}>(e: A2): Promise<boolean> */
```

You can see that it infers that `e` should be of type `A2` (since it `Zoom`s to `A1 | A2` with `name`, and then `Zoom`s further to `A2` with `type`, and then the subsequent `Zoom`ing does no further narrowing), and so the error is focused on the `subType` property.  One more:

```
trackIt({
    name: "B",
    type: 2, // error!
    // Type '2' is not assignable to type '1'.
    location: "be",
    subType: "oops" // error!
    // Type '"oops"' is not assignable to type '"not" | "probably"'.
});
/* function trackIt<{
    name: "B";
    type: 2;
    location: "be";
    subType: "oops";
}>(e: B): Promise<boolean> */
```

Here, the `name` property of `e` causes the compiler to `Zoom` from `Events` down to `B`, where it stays.  And therefore the `type` and `subType` properties are both flagged as not conforming to `B`.

---

Whew!  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIEZkG8BQz-IhwC2EAXMgESqUDceBYAngA7nLr0HIA2A9gjhhgfEBUoBnPqUrIAPlQlgooAOayFlHsEhQ4PDVWZsJdBvgkBXAEYAVVu0rE+UCIcnK177bv3vjEKb0AL44OKC68EhoAEzY5oQkjjRcjA4UMan4-ILCouJSMvKKniDqxVo60H4VAaYVgiDu1m4VEgAWcK4AJmbcVnbpVCB8YO4dXRC9IWER0FEoAELx3ESk4ot9aWwUnAk5QiJiVAh8ljy9bcI8BhUt4509WxY29jtULFB81nDWPEzuEZjGbhcDzRAoADCKwIa0ckOehFGQ0oMGAEAu-kCwJwoRwAWQAFEAG4QcASZAAXjQmAUqDiCmWCkh9DCAHo2cgAJLdAAeAB5bAAaZAAaQAfLw+HwANYUywsZBgdooUXIT58NhQZjIPgwZDC3VQZCuMCWKAgCkgCCk434hzcvmCkVqiC8yAgboUmUQJh65BwEBMSXU13usle5A+v362zIAD8BoA2qKALrICjW22sjncmAAORt0GdyAAapKbfpLEJAkq+AbkJYQDxAhS48ArUWoCLQMgAO7tYAIdrIQQSFA6ZAdsv2th5wu2kvlqnIJO2dNuj2RpNZ6DpxOljMG9mcgAiHYQKmIoBriyY-IAqi6RbZJWA4D6KXBGyAjkqHU+AZRr6-5zqKIqBt0QGNN0wDdDWOC5gShqQYkUBfH2FIPnWAY3Eq7R8OO-YEURxJVrWQj4aq6pfFqOrEEIw74UIiGcv6tgAHT4LYg4UteqjtGAyARo2iqmuav5lIQXY9vqyrQBOVr1gxYDDhxs4oOeEiXsA15EJAd6Pi6wnhp63q+v6gZMC+IYJNhm4Rl+QYJo6AqGhKJlbhSPICoBHmJthmZdkeu5QCeyAAFrSsQRlijZU4UhIunADwXQ4VpCDJfpECGX5NkitYlhCcAckqq4CVIqxyAqUxk7iRaFLycgMDnDwP5-g+6kElF0ixWGXnATGAZBjZCTUlyBZdvyGVXjeBn3nlBriiKD7ijmnIAOLAKSIBEiKJJkmAEgAOo6O0iwQGAuiEuhLgSPyhKSpY44Uj1xA4TAAjPVOu2iFVTUHeS7WiMg1hMKO0gsF0aiJKQIoBCKBx5CAEGesgAxvCgGp0eiEhClVvbKpRLjdNAXHIBpRI7Udp3KhdV0uDdXxQPdj1UgkhKeY5VOHRSiac2QCRvfywui9FD3U3jwxJJQ+3LUYDiy0Sy0JNwWgCIcohK49IqSK8ity+FTWCHhSWqPp5ooP6yiIDKXLFRSqhktAQ4igOClUcJ6pdEkuj9ilPBVS0P0wNAPQBhSnTEjDBKEqjUGTtO8m7acxBQ+HYD1oDNNnfT123SzD3ijgcASEwIAIM1TYIMjSp6AgdtgEXAAU7DZydueXZnUBM3dRcAJQUAACl817jvy1jSi2gZrVVPoQIqTVJWnLbGrpLAtqQ4Ca7tZsW64JdlxXVcV7XNsN-bzdYLDEAihx99Q0w-BwFBwQUO3-cwvg9W7colgQCCc+jcr4JDhOIGg+NuABF2JAggSMjjiDqLLBIGMUQ+GqAYXEn9cyyjgEwMIQDL64FWEkcByCoFDBiLA7IGtkYFGkG4ah6N9bvEoNKFg9RcxhxcAAQgSLmTGyAADkbDNSmCERVIEEc96-BbDhAkIiJhPAqECSgQj1LBH7vQNkAAqE+Nc-yEKbsQ2EpCqApASNA5AmR9i0IQYoBhiJUGsPYUEXE4pW4UHpIPZAI9pAdggBPKeEAZ7IB0WyAh9dgEmPwGAqgmwmFWKocgLhBc+HcAEQ6IRMQJHTikaXGRfwUCZ1AigIR6B1G2NyPYyg9wmHOMcK42QqTmbpIIJkucIimm5KUkJApwBzayOKfWBRlBVEVA1D8P4AJKmaO0Xolqp9DFRPtvyGJN8NiIiSVkKU1T8hUHuDshp4gmkhA8ewRYPi-Fj0CZPPg08QCSnCWEIAA)

Comment: I'm reviewing your answer now, but I wanted to just say thank you for being a hero and doing this much thorough explanation in your answer. You rock! I'm inevitably going to be able to learn a thing or two from all of those Generic type usages :D

Comment: EventsWithBetterErrors generic type on the conditional type does it fall to the Zoom method because on incorrect usages E doesn't perfectly match Events? I think that's the piece of the puzzle I'm missing for full understanding. Your answer definitely works so marking as the accepted answer!

Comment: Yeah... if `E` matches `Events`, hooray, the end.  Otherwise, it does that `Zoom` thing a bunch of times to try to figure out which members of `Events` are "closest" to `E`.  That's what `E extends Events ? E : Zoom<Zoom<....` means.

Comment: So cool. Thank you. Added your code to my production use case and voila, problem solved. :)

Comment: Well, you should test it out thoroughly, of course.... these type-juggling exercises with conditional and generic types can have, uh, "interesting" behavior.  I'd recommend them only for direct user-level calls of the function.  If you have other functions call the function, you might need some type assertions.    I don't know, the word "production" makes me jittery.  I need a "this code is for entertainment purposes only" disclaimer or something.  Anyway, good luck!

Comment: Well, luckily the code you provided is like 95% only type signatures so they'll be stripped before it's shipped :D