# Narrowing down types and types variants based on Input

Tags: typescript, types, conditional-statements, typescript-generics

First i needed to write a function which narrows down a Type based on the input object of the function. This [Article](https://artsy.github.io/blog/2018/11/21/conditional-types-in-typescript/) helped me great with it but now i also need to narrow down the generic of the type based on the input and i cannot get it to work after several hours of trying

This is my given typescript of the project simplified:

```
const ToolType = {
  TOOL_A: 'toolA',
  TOOL_B: 'toolB',
  TOOL_C: 'toolC',
} as const;

type ToolType = typeof ToolType[keyof typeof ToolType];

const ToolAVariants = {
  Variant_A : 'VariantA',
  Variant_B : 'VariantB',
  Variant_C : 'VariantC',
} as const

type ToolAVariants = typeof ToolAVariants[keyof typeof ToolAVariants];

type VariantASettings = {
  setting: 'A'
  type: typeof ToolAVariants.Variant_A
}
type VariantBSettings = {
  setting: 'B'
  type: typeof ToolAVariants.Variant_B
}
type VariantCSettings = {
  setting: 'C'
  type: typeof ToolAVariants.Variant_C
}
type VariantSettings = VariantASettings | VariantBSettings | VariantCSettings

type ToolA<T extends ToolAVariants> = {
  type: typeof ToolType.TOOL_A
  width: number
  Settings: ExtractActionParametersBase<VariantSettings, T>
}
type ToolB = {
  type: typeof ToolType.TOOL_B,
  height: string

}
type ToolC = {
  type: typeof ToolType.TOOL_C
  length: any[]

type MyToolTypes = ToolA<typeof ToolAVariants.Variant_A> | ToolA<typeof ToolAVariants.Variant_B> | ToolA<typeof ToolAVariants.Variant_C> | ToolB | ToolC
```

using the utility type from the article

```
type ExtractActionParameters<A, T> = A extends { type: T } ? A : never
```

For UI purposes i need also to add an `ìd` to the Tools like this

```
type ToolIdWrapper<T extends MyToolTypes> = T & { id: string }
```

This is the function:

```
function createTool<T extends MyToolTypes['type'], Z extends VariantSettings['type']>(args: ExtractActionParameters<MyToolTypes, T>): ToolIdWrapper<typeof args> {
  return {
    id: 'someid',
    ...args
  }
}
```

it works fine if i create a tool which has not the "variant" :

```
const MyToolB_Wrapped: ToolIdWrapper<ToolB> = createTool({
  height: 'qwe',
  type: "toolB",
}) // -> no error
```

but trying to create a ToolA variant, the Settings property is not correctly narrowed down and still a union type

```
const MyToolA_Wrapped:ToolIdWrapper<ToolA<typeof ToolAVariants.Variant_A>> = createTool({
  width: 123,
  type: 'toolA',
  Settings: {
    setting: "A",
    type: "VariantA"
  }
}) // Error
```

which throws this TS error: `Type 'ToolIdWrapper<ToolA<"VariantA"> | ToolA<"VariantB"> | ToolA<"VariantC">>' is not assignable to type 'ToolIdWrapper<ToolA<"VariantA">>`

I basicly need a function typing which does not throw an error in this case and the other cases

I tried expanding the utility type like this

```
type ExtractActionParameters<A, T> = A extends { type: T } ? A extends {Settings: VariantSettings} ? A | {Settings: A['Settings']} : A : never
```

or other variants of if/else-ing with the conditional extends, but i couldn't get it to work.

For better debugging i created this [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAKiEAbOBPADgUxgXhgbwFgAoGeAeXIBkB9AQQC4YByKRJO5gGhLLktoAhJq3aDuvCtRoBhEW2QyJxAL4wAhhBihIUANwkSUDNgTI0WXDGNYQAM3jsLmANoBrTKnvWT3syhMAXQNiEh1oR2Q6ADV1ACcAS3UwKC08IlIYWMTkqHoYEWyklM4eTKLcmkEClgqU8TKyOryZGuZmpTK1TW1waENiG1N2GPji1KshvxHmiHdPbymHf1GclIhggaGssdy6AGVMKCgEsABzNIJJCCOT85FOSSGmJciOWYA6ZvoSFSMTHZrKCCQ7HU4XKwZMg3MH3FjiJ4mF6+ZYzXbrL7ovKCX7-SwdUF3CHpa63cEiJSIrDI2yoqKfb4yXGDAHNQngy7NA5k85aAA+gPGIJ5EIFBJFEAGeOGUQAPHAYJgAB5QTBgAAmWhWswAfJCqZgaZhpuYTB9+NI6JIAO4JdVQAAWTDAAFcALYAI0wcUk7N5TAAoiq4upgFA6GGEuAAArxdRuo7eiCytkSrjwHXM7b+aokzLPHy0t7Oc0CKqNGAOzAJM4OqBMaCJc4DP4syz+Vp5sgF17+EsW2hMzJINVnR1MZKoFyBZkkAD0c5gAHUQHE3OCYLbHb1dFprau3Fo7KdMGE+rBonQAEoASToADk4LJyPf9k-o1fKAAxBj+G-qpcQ3QLA4nlEZZV7NEgQgTEgXoHU9S7GA7REABHa1MGUMhbXtJ0YAARgAJgAZgrAtRCiLCYD9C4mChMgYBhIkHio7skRgAAiLkOMkVtWzPXQYAAWVQDtf3Yf9APUYDvTAxREKuTIUJYYiqJHc5xxgacyPYiikEpVQtlZeJLhWCCUTeVZxhg746D1AUzMg+ksRsrEqnsyzzKLbUXNg8ZZEzNtsBEvsTE5EyYAcsRIreIdswkgCgJA+VFRVNVNWE0SnDChSFQAMgIZD1QbKAmzOGB+KCmAg1K0Nw0jGM4wTVU4mTOh0zgBS6FS1UNS0fBC0NeAKpgAB+GBuudTAADdvXnOdthqkMwwjE5GpDZqk1ldqMysbrlV6jKBoLBU1HG-a0r6ggaIgJhU1hC4zommL8Bupg6BcZgbuYQI1HemowBmubQmIBcYC-F0wAasBNwdBJgAdGAwHiOIQGtLR1TRmG4iOF04hh7ZpqSDQ4ghIGYa3RGzjVb14clYg7Eh6HtBx9RVX8FKDvSrQQuyrA5lYEwfp1AAKeJaOq4M6tWqMwFjDbE1a2VedNfmOp1ABKJg-0S6TktecWID1eicagPGYfoshlOYCAQATO1WJgD5ncN3jZ1BxcIAdEAXSQdUkZAWBHVR61FTiVGfWIcIL2vO9HxoL8AFV7xoD9vxofDxOQSSktkxyLJ86C-MqOyFOAVn2fYEX6JwzSiNIg15BGKi3sUhjGJFJgOLoDiKzY6lOO4t3VA1gYwa9n2-ZgL1BreHO9bz8CnPeXzbIQ5DdEwdR-e8SHZYEiJL1vB8nyTlO0-IL8aEIqxy63yvkGrmAbTtOuSJ0ge9NKX0JToyRoU7pxHufdBpdyHpkPio8QZSmgbAgYQA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it was a too big wall of text and hard to understand, BUT i finally got to a solution which is working.

First, big thanks to [this answer in this article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58563419/12365729), which helped me figuring this out

**Recap**

The Target was to define a function which returns a specific type based on the input structure. The difficulty lies in in the nested type discrimination against a property in the input, which is not present in all inputs.

e.G. We got `TypeA`, `TypeB` and `TypeC` of which the `TypeA` only got a additional property `TypeA.Variant` which can further differentiate into `TypeA<VariantA>`, `TypeA<VariantB>` and `TypeA<VariantC>`

**Solution**

```
const ToolType = {
  TOOL_A: 'toolA',
  TOOL_B: 'toolB',
  TOOL_C: 'toolC',
} as const;

type ToolType = typeof ToolType[keyof typeof ToolType];

const ToolAVariants = {
  Variant_A : 'VariantA',
  Variant_B : 'VariantB',
  Variant_C : 'VariantC',
} as const

type ToolAVariants = typeof ToolAVariants[keyof typeof ToolAVariants];


// A
type ToolA<T extends ToolAVariants> = {
  type: typeof ToolType.TOOL_A
  width: number
  Settings: T extends typeof ToolAVariants.Variant_A ? VariantASettings : T extends typeof ToolAVariants.Variant_B ? VariantBSettings : VariantCSettings
}
// A Variants in Object
type VariantASettings = {
  setting: 'A'
  type: typeof ToolAVariants.Variant_A
}
type VariantBSettings = {
  setting: 'B'
  type: typeof ToolAVariants.Variant_B
}
type VariantCSettings = {
  setting: 'C'
  type: typeof ToolAVariants.Variant_C
}

// B
type ToolB = {
  type: typeof ToolType.TOOL_B,
  height: string
}
// C
type ToolC = {
  type: typeof ToolType.TOOL_C
  length: any[]
}

// Union of all possible Tools
type MyToolTypes = ToolB | ToolC | ToolA<typeof ToolAVariants.Variant_A> | ToolA<typeof ToolAVariants.Variant_B> | ToolA<typeof ToolAVariants.Variant_C>

// Idx<T, K> looks up the K property of T, or returns never 
type Idx<T, K extends keyof any> = K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never;

// DiscriminateBy<U, K, T> takes a union type U, a key type K, and a candidate
// type T, and narrows U to all those whose values at the K property match that
// of T.  This might end up returning never, if there is no match.
type DiscriminateBy<U, K extends keyof any, T> = U extends any ? Idx<T, K> extends Idx<U, K> ? U : never : never

//  (in my eyes) TS Magic - Use DiscriminateBy to extract the types, we want to discriminate against in a nested fashion
type DiscriminateTypeAndSettings<E> = E extends MyToolTypes ? E : DiscriminateBy<DiscriminateBy<MyToolTypes, "type", E>, "Settings", E>


type IDWrapper<T> = T & { id: string }
function creatTool<E>(e: DiscriminateTypeAndSettings<E>): IDWrapper<DiscriminateTypeAndSettings<E>> {
    return {
      id:'someId',
      ...e
      };
}


// Works!
const A_VariantA:IDWrapper<ToolA<typeof ToolAVariants.Variant_A>> = creatTool({
  type: 'toolA',
  width: 123,
  Settings: {
    setting: "A",
    type: 'VariantA'
  },
})

// Error as Intended! -> Setting needs to be {setting:'A', type: 'VariantC'}
const A_VariantA_TRAP:IDWrapper<ToolA<typeof ToolAVariants.Variant_A>> = creatTool({
  type: 'toolA',
  width: 123,
  Settings: {
    setting: "C",
    type: 'VariantC'
  },
})

// Error as Intended! -> setting needs to be "B"
const A_VariantB:IDWrapper<ToolA<typeof ToolAVariants.Variant_B>> = creatTool({
  type: 'toolA',
  width: 123,
  Settings: {
    setting: "C",
    type: 'VariantB'
  },
})
```

**The coolest thing**
is, that i even could make "SubTypes" of the `Variants` and add another layer of `DiscriminateBy` - utililty type infinitely

Although i don't really understand how the `DiscriminateBy` Type works, i am very happy that it works